# I need to create a Subtitle in sql with database values

Tags: sql

I have a table with values similar like:

`select * from persons`

```
Name  Age Country    Sex
------------------------
Fede  22  Argentina  M
Paul  24  USA        M
Sarah 31  USA        F
Pablo 32  Colombia   M
```

I need a query that the column country acts as a Subtitle, like this:

```
Argentina
----------------
Fede      22  M
----------------
Colombia
----------------
Pablo     32  M
----------------
USA
----------------
Paul      24  M
----------------
Sarah     31  F
```

I don´t know how I can obtain a similar result like that.

EDIT

```
Country A
tuples of people from country A
Country B
tuples of people from country B
Country C
tuples of people from country C


This is the ouput i need from the query
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Also, this is more appropriately done in the application layer than in the database.

Comment: SQL isn't really the best tool to handle data display like this. It would be simpler to off load this task to the presentation software.

Comment: This question is related to reporting, rather than SQL. SQL is only part of the solution. You should include a reporting tool in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @country nvarchar(30)
Declare c Cursor For Select Distinct Country From persons
Open c

Fetch next From c into @country

While @@Fetch_Status=0 Begin
    Print 'Country : ' + @country
    select Name, Age, Sex from persons
    Fetch next From c into @country
End

Close c
Deallocate c
```

You can use cursor but it may EAT up a lot of CPU memory. It's my suggestion to use code at your front end to achieve this. It is not a good practice at the Database level.

Comment: Just edit the post, because it looks weird. Your anwser doesnt serve to me

Comment: Maybe I am not able to understand your requirement. Can you edit your requirement including column name? just like your original table having columns. where exactly subtitle should place? If it is related to presentation then SQL can't help in this. You have to handle it in the Presentation layer.

Comment: The coutry its like a Subtitle, it goes before the tuple of person